# Convert vb.net asp.net code to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

```
Checked='<%# iif(eval("isActive")="True","False","True")  %>'
```

What is the equivalent in c# for asp.net?  I have tried my best to convert it but i could not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Checked='<%# !(bool)Eval("isActive") %>'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Checked='<%# (bool)Eval("isActive") ? false : true %>'
```